# How I can add score in the game LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a clon of Flappy Bird game, but without score, how I can add it? Can somebody help mi?

Comment: Please read [ask] a good question and edit your question to make it answerable.

Answer (score 0):

libGDX does not have special facilities for creating and displaying a score. You need to make it as an int and display it as you would any other text yourself. Hope this answers your question.